# Setting axis labels when scaling tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Here is my code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}[
    view/h=150, view/v=10,
    axis equal,
    axis lines=center, ticks=none,
    xmin=-2, xmax=2, ymin=-3, ymax=5, zmin=-2, zmax=2,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    zlabel={$z$},
    ]
\addplot3 [
    domain=0:360,
    samples=50,
    red,
    thick,
    ]
    ({cos(x)},{0},{sin(x)});    

\addplot3[
    opacity=0.7,
    mesh,
    gray,
    z buffer=sort,
    samples=50,
    variable=\u,
    variable y=\v,
    domain=0:360,
    y domain=0:2
    ]
    ({cos(u)},{v},{sin(u)});
\addplot3 [
    domain=0:360,
    samples=50,
    red,
    thick,
    ]
    ({cos(x)},{2},{sin(x)});
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

And here is my image.

[image]

How can I place the labels at the tip of each axis? Also, because I used scale=1.5 above, the fonts have been enlarged. How can I resize them inside my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the tick labels with styles of the form

```
xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=east}
```

at the desired positions. If you want the tick labels to come closer to the tips of the arrows, reduce `1.05` to a smaller value. In order to increase the plot, do not use `scale` but change the `width` of the `axis`. It makes sense to decrease the `samples y` to 0 where you just draw 1-dimensional plots. Also you may want to redraw the visible part of the y axis in order to make the picture a bit more 3d-like. The `fillbetween` library is loaded because it loads `intersections` and thus allows us to determine this visible part.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}[width=12cm,
    view/h=150, view/v=10,
    axis equal,
    axis lines=center, ticks=none,
    xmin=-2, xmax=2, ymin=-3, ymax=5, zmin=-2, zmax=2,
    xlabel={$x$},xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=east},
    ylabel={$y$},ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=160},
    zlabel={$z$},zlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south},
    ]
\addplot3 [
    domain=0:360,
    samples=50,
    red,
    thick,samples y=0,
    ]
    ({cos(x)},{0},{sin(x)});    

\addplot3[
    opacity=0.7,
    mesh,
    gray,
    z buffer=sort,
    samples=50,
    variable=\u,
    variable y=\v,
    domain=0:360,
    y domain=0:2,%samples y=2,
    ]
    ({cos(u)},{v},{sin(u)});
\addplot3 [name path=front,
    domain=0:360,
    samples=50,
    red,
    thick,samples y=0,
    ]
    ({cos(x)},{2},{sin(x)});
\path[name path=yaxis] (0,0,0) -- (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax},0);
\draw[name intersections={of=front and yaxis}]
 (intersection-1) -- (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}-0.1,0);
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, for the future I'd kindly like to ask you to provide complete but minimal codes that start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.